# How to prevent an Excel spreadsheet inserted into a Onenote page from changing size after each edit?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I have an Excel spreadsheet on a Onenote page, and every time I edit the sheet's cells (without adding or removing cells to change the total dimensions), the Onenote page refreshes it to a roughly 120% scale and it looks weird. To make it look nice again, I have to right-click and select "Restore to original size". How do I make it stop resizing on its own after every edit so I don't need to do that?